Fetching characters from a Buffer while reading Ints
I am building a language interpreter and needs to have two functions, one to input an integer and another to input a character (from System.in). For instance, inputting integer - character - integer - character - character - character from
123 C
456
DEF

should give 123, C, 456, D, E, and F.
Edit: Similarly, inputting integer - character - integer from
123 456

should give 123, 4, and 56.
With my current implementation, I can either get 123, C, 456, D (by exhausting the current input line) or get 123, C, 456, E, F (skipping over any character that is in the first of line).
My code is:
class Variable extends Var {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static String buffer = ""; // Buffer to hold unprocessed characters
    private static int bufferIndex = 0; // Index to track the next character in the buffer
    private String name;

    public Variable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(HashMap<String, Integer> values) {
        return name;
    }

    public int evaluate(HashMap<String, Integer> values) {
        if (name.equals("read")) {
            return scanner.nextInt();
        }
        if (name.equals("get")) {
            // Refill buffer if empty or fully processed
            while (bufferIndex >= buffer.length()) {
                    buffer = scanner.nextLine();
                    bufferIndex = 0; // Reset the index for the new buffer
            }
            // Return the ASCII value of the next character in the buffer
            return (int) buffer.charAt(bufferIndex++);
        }
        return values.getOrDefault(name, 0);
    }
}


I don't really get what you're doing.  You give an example in the text of the question, but then in the code you're looking for strings like "read" and "get".  What are those strings used for?

StreamTokenizer makes this quite easy: private void collectData() throws IOException {try (Reader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in)) {StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(in);while (st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {switch (st.ttype) {case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER -> numbers.add((int)st.nval);case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD -> characters.add(st.sval);}}}}

If you want separate word characters, you can do case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD -> characters.addAll(st.sval.codePoints().mapToObj(Character::toString).toList());

Actually, what I really want is two separate functionalities: "read" for reading a number, and "get" for getting a character. I still want it to be able to "get" from a number, so read - get - read from 123 456 will give 123, 4 (or rather, ord(4)), and 56. I'll update that in my question.

How would you get "123, 4, and 56" from an input of 123 456? With no delimiter between the 4 and the 5, on what basis would you separate that input?

4 is read as a character.

That doesn't make any sense

Scanner is the mostly wrong tool for the job. Or, at least, the way you're using it.
Scanner is a thing that separates input into tokens and returns those. Tokens are defined as 'the things in between the delimiter', and the delimiter is set up by default as 'any amount of whitespace'.
What you want is a funky delimiter: "Any amount of spaces, including none at all, between 2 characters, but at least 1 space between 2 digits".
This gets you into fancy regexes that are unreadable unless you are very familiar with them.
You'll learn a lot more if you skip all that and find another way to do it. For example, just grab individual characters. Only if the character you fetch is a digit and the previous character was also a digit, combine them into a new number, otherwise, you got a token.
Forget Scanner, it was never meant for keyboard input anyway.
class MyApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new MyApp().go();
  }

  StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();

  void go() throws IOException {
    while (true) {
      int v = System.in.read();
      if (v == -1) {
        cycleToken();
        return;
      }
      
      char w = (char) v;
      if (w >= '0' && w <= '9') {
        token.append(w);
      } else {
        cycleToken();
        token.append(w);
        cycleToken();
      }
    }
  }

  void cycleToken() {
    String z = token.toString().trim();
    if (!z.isEmpty()) System.out.println("TOKEN: " + z);
    token.setLength(0);
  }
}


StringBuilder is a mutable string. We need it here to add numbers; we don't know when we're "done" with a number until we see a non-number, or the end of input.
Any non-digit can be emitted as token immediately; only digits are 'saved' to be emitted later, because another digit might come next.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79279976/fetching-characters-from-a-buffer-while-reading-ints#comment139802817_79279976

(But of course, thank you regardless.)

@Sny It feels like you're now asking 'do my homework for me'. With the above approach you can make exactly what you want rather easily.

I've already implemented what I wanted, but I thought I'd update the question.

@Sny Awesome, glad to hear you made some progress on your project :)
